# Get distinct list between two lists in C#

Tags: c#, list, distinct-values, set-difference

I have two lists of strings. How do I get the list of distinct values between them or remove the second list elements from the first list?

```
List<string> list1 = { "see","you","live"}

List<string> list2 = { "see"}
```

The result should be `{"you","live"}`.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It looks to me like you need [`Enumerable.Except()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx):

```
var differences = list1.Except(list2);
```

And then you can loop through the differences:

```
foreach(var difference in differences)
{
    // work with each individual string here.
}
```

Comment: how i can get the elements of " differences" ? its var not list

Comment: @salamonti - The var keyword is just a shortcut. In that case, it would be an IEnumerable<string> that you could iterate over.

Comment: I never liked var being used unless absolutely necessary, but nonetheless, chrs for the example

Answer (score 14):

If you want to get items from the first list except items in the second list, use

```
list1.Except(list2)
```

If you want to get items that are in the first list or in the second list, but not both, you can use

```
list1.Except(list2).Concat(list2.Except(list1))
```

Comment: If anybody comes here for for "items that are in the first list or in the second list, but not both", you can simply use `list1.Union(list2)`

Comment: I misunderstood your comment expected the union result to not contain any of the items that were duplicates. I realized Union is just the deduped merger of 2 lists.

Answer (score 6):

> This is the good way I find unique....
>
> Unique from two list

```
        var A = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4 };
        var B = new List<int>() { 1, 5, 6, 7 };

       var a= A.Except(B).ToList();
        // outputs List<int>(2) { 2,3,4 }
       var b= B.Except(A).ToList();
        // outputs List<int>(2) { 5,6,7 }
       var abint=  B.Intersect(A).ToList();
        // outputs List<int>(2) { 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.
Find distinct values in two int lists and assign those values to the third int list.

```
List<int> list1 = new List <int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }; 
List<int> list2 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9 };
List<int> list3 = new List<int>();
var DifferentList1 = list1.Except(list2).Concat(list2.Except(list1));

foreach (var item in DifferentList1)
{
    list3.Add(item);

}

foreach (var item in list3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Different Item found in lists are{0}",item);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.